# IllegalStateException when MediaRecorder is recording: how to fix

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-mediarecorder

I got this issue and cant get my head around it, im recording calls directly from the speaker, so when i get TelephonyManager.`CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` I instantly start recording audio from `VOICE_CALL`. thats part its ok, start recording but if the call is ended and start a new one, I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

I think this is because the first call it's still being recorded... I've tried to do:
    `mRecorder.stop();`
     `mRecorder.release();`
     `mRecorder.reset();`
but no luck, they all gave me a `illegalStateException`, I just want to know how to stop first call recording and record a new one without errors.

Here's my code for recording and call handling,

```
//At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.
if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){

    if (record_calls == 1){
        record_enviroment();
    }
}

//when Idle = No activity.
if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
     //Check for audio recorded and if exists post audio to server
}

public void record_enviroment(){

path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";

try {

//Random number for file name
Random r = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
i = 10000 + r.nextInt(20000);

// Save file local to app
mFileName = path + i + "_call_" + id_asociado + ".3gp";
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

try {
     mRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("AUDIO_RECORDER", "prepare() failed");
}

mRecorder.start();

} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Where you able to solve the problem?